# Any way to get a page-scoped-id from app-scoped-id on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, passport-facebook

As many of you already know, when a user logins on one of our Facebook Apps, we get some data and there is a user ID that only works for the App world.

If we have, let's say, a bot that we want to use to interact with the user, we need an ID that is unique to the page associated with that bot. In order to get it, I have been reading this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/customer-matching

Obviously, we want to send a message to the user as soon as he/she is logged in, without previous interaction. We tried with the Graph API:

```
<user-app-scoped-id>?fields=name,age_range,ids_for_apps,ids_for_pages&access_token=<user-access-token>
```

And we get something like this:

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "ids_for_apps": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1006086616200000",
        "app": {
          "link": "http://public-link/",
          "name": "ChatBotTest",
          "id": "1171064089667000"            
       }
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTE3MTA2NDA4OTY2NTE3",
        "after": "MTE3MTA2NDA4OTY2NTE3"
      }
    }
  },
  "ids_for_pages": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1599402636786000",
        "page": {
          "name": "TuHuella",
          "id": "1931527867112000"
        }
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTkzMTUyNzg2NzExMjU1MAZDZD",
        "after": "MTkzMTUyNzg2NzExMjU1MAZDZD"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "1006086616200000"
}
```

The last part "ids_for_pages", only appears if the user wrote something to our page, so it seems that we need this interaction.

Anybody knows a way to avoid this? maybe we can programmatically send a message from the logged in user to our Page so we get this interaction?

Thanks a lot,

Ricardo

Comment: Extra information: just liking the page is not enough, only works with a message sent.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking, resp. what your problem is. Your bot can never start the initial interaction with the user, the user needs to do that.

Comment: So, you are stating that the customer matching tool only works after the user started interaction too?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin

See an example here:

https://signup.pushblack.us/

This is it. All I need is the checkbox Facebook plugin. If the user is already logged in (which will surely be) then the checkbox is already checked and upon clicking on any button, we can trigger the message sent from our server.

If the user is not logged in, then the checkbox is not checked and if the user clicks on it, it will prompt a login box and check the checkbox if successful.

Neat.

Comment: this how you get page_scope_id use to send message via the messeger? can tell me more about your way?